# WCF REST Service Pass object as parameter in POST method

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a method in my WCF Service.

```
[OperationContract]           
[FaultContract(typeof(Hitachi.WebServices.Common.WebServiceFaultException))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "Syslog/AddServerConfiguration")]
void AddServerConfiguration(ServerConnectionInfo  serverConnectionInfo);
```

From the client side , I am using `HttpWebRequest`` . I am consistently getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

To pass the parameter serverConnectionInfo, I tried different options -

[1] Using simple String formatter -

```
String body = string.Format("{{\"serverConnectionInfo\":{{\"DeviceIP\":\"{0}\",\"Password\":\"{1}\",\"Port\":0,\"UserName\":\"{2}\"}}}}", ipAddress, password, userName);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
{
    byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
    request.GetRequestStream().Close();
}
```

[2] Using `JavaScriptSerializer` -

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = jss.Serialize(connInfo);
String body = string.Format("{{\"serverConnectionInfo\":{0}}}", data);
```

[3] Using `JsonConvert` -

```
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { serverConnectionInfo = connInfo });
request.ContentLength = body.Length;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(body);
writer.Close();
```

[4]Using `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

I like to point out that I am using `DataContract` for `ServerConnectionInfo`. Moreover, inside my class `ServerConnectionInfo` , I have `string` and `int` data members. I am properly setting `ContentType` and `ContentLength` for `HttpWebRequest`.

This method works perfectly well with REST client "POSTMAN".

What am I missing ?

Comment: How to call a REST WCF? HttpClient ?HttpWebRequest?  RestSharp?

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the following line ( not mentioned in the problem) in my code and it starts working.

```
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset:utf-8";
```

changed to

```
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Now, my doubt is , what is wrong in specifying charset in content type of request.

Comment: It should be `charset=utf-8`. The `:` character is what caused your 400.